# In OS X Lion, asking the Finder for the current selection, returns the wrong file

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, osx-lion

I've confirmed that this is only happening in Lion. I've uncovered what appears to be a bug where you need to focus a window twice in order for Finder to return the correct result over the scripting bridge or AppleScript. This only happens when opening a folder from the desktop or another space.

Here's how to duplicate:

1. Close, hide or minimize all windows until the desktop is showing.
2. Open any folder on the desktop, a new finder window will appear. Select any file in that finder window by clicking on it once.
3. Open your AppleScript Editor and run the following script:

   ```
   tell application "Finder"
       return selection
   end tell
   ```

The script will return *only the path to the folder on the desktop, not the selected file* in the finder window.

If you refocus the window, or click on the file again, everything works as expected and the script returns the correct path.

This seems like a bug in Lion. Snow Leopard returns the correct path 100% of the time.

I've tried the following methods with no success:

1. Using the scripting bridge and https://github.com/davedelong/BetterInfo/blob/master/Finder.h
2. Using "System Events" apple script to click "Edit"->"Copy"
3. Using AppleScript to get the current selection from the finder.

All seem to have have the same issue.

Am I missing something obvious or is this truly a problem with Lion?

Comment: That does seem to be a bug. And a problem when I move some of my Macs to Lion, as some of my apps use scripting bridge and NSApplescript to get finder selections.

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug to Apple. Track it here: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1467403

Comment: I've submitted it to Apple as well. Sadly, next month 10.8 comes out, and it's still having the same bug in Preview 4. Apple, WTF! (Oh, just seeing that your report actually refers to mine, meaning I was the first to report this. Shit, this isn't going well. I liked Apple more when they were still fixing bugs like this.)

Comment: This bug had not been fixed in Mountain Lion (10.8.0).

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I can confirm (at least through applescript) most of what you describe. I was getting an empty list returned, not even the desktop path you mention. I was testing this using a script in the applescript menu. The only way I could get the selection from a fresh Finder window was like this...

```
tell application "System Events" to activate
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set a to (get selection) as text
    display dialog a
end tell
```

Comment: Activating the finder is not always desired when running from other applications. I wish apple would give us another way to get whats selected in finder.

Comment: Yeah the problem is, even if the finder is activated, that script blinks the focus on and off, which is a pretty weird user interface experience.

Comment: It is clearly a bug in the Finder, not something Apple has intended. It used to work before Lion, and it works once you re-activate the Finder. Therefore, "wishing" is not helpful. Only reporting this to Apple is. I did report it. Did you? If not, do it now!